# How can I get linkedin contacts through API and send messages to them?

Tags: linkedin-api

I had created app that used to get authenticated by users for their contacts, sending messages to those contacts etc. When linked in changed their API access system in May, suddenly our application stopped working.

In the doc there is nothing clearly written about these kind of permissions now or with what kind of membership program I can get access to these again. There is one section where contacts info can be fetched when we apply for partnership program with Apply with LinkedIn button. But I am not sure its of my use.

Answer (score 3):

**Access to `r_contactinfo` permission:**

As per the Linkedin website,

> The r_contactinfo member permission will now be associated exclusively
>   with Apply with LinkedIn.  As a result, you will only be able to
>   request this member permission if your application has been approved
>   by LinkedIn for this particular use.

**What you need to do:**

Apply for partner status with LinkedIn ([Apply with Linkedin](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/apply-with-linkedin)), explaining what your integration is and how it works. If it meets their criteria, then you will get access to the above endpoint.

Check this [link](https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition) for further details.